# Pandas apply formula to each row and find minimum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I'm looking for an efficient way to apply a formula using variables from a single row of one dataframe (df1) against every row in another datframe (df2), then find the minimum value of this operation and store the row from df2 in which this minimum value occured as a new dataframe (df3).
example input/output is given.

```
df1                
Index   X1  Y1  Z1      
1       3   6   4        
2       7   2   1       
3       4   7   3       

df2
Index   X2  Y2  Z2
1       2   4   1
2       5   3   2
3       7   1   5
```

Formuala to apply:

```
d = math.sqrt((X2-X1)**2 + (Y2-Y1)**2 + (Z2-Z1)**2)
```

If this formula was to be applied iteratively to df2, where (X1, Y1, Z1) is from df1 row1 and (X2, Y2, Z2) are taken from each row in df2 to give.

```
[out]
Index  d
1      3.741
2      4.123
3      6.481
```

Since (X2, Y2, Z2) in df2 row 1 provided the lowest d value, this row would be saved into df3 and the process then repeated for each row in df1.

```
df3
Index  X2  Y2  Z2  
1      2   4   1
```

*Note, df1 and df2 are of different length. Apologies if this question seems long-winded, I'm just trying to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) can be used for this with its default Euclidean distance metric:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

df3 = df2.iloc[cdist(df1, df2).argmin(axis=1)]
```

`cdist` gives back a `(n1, n2)` shaped array where `n1` and `n2` are number of rows in `df1` and `df2` respectively. Then we look at the index of the minimum distance for each row to see which row of `df2` gave rise to it. `iloc` then selects these from `df2`,

to get

```
>>> df3

       X2  Y2  Z2
Index
1       2   4   1
2       5   3   2
1       2   4   1
```

---

the intermediate results:

```
>>> cdist(df1, df2)

# first row is your calculations in the question, for example
array([[3.74165739, 4.12310563, 6.4807407 ],
       [5.38516481, 2.44948974, 4.12310563],
       [4.12310563, 4.24264069, 7.        ]])

>>> cdist(df1, df2).argmin(axis=1)

array([0, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

i.e., for 0th and 2nd row of `df1`, 0th row of `df2` is selected; for 1st row of `df1`, 1st row of `df2` is selected (0 indexed).

---

As you remind the time-memory tradeoff, here is a for loop implementation:

```
# will keep the minimum distance rows' indices
min_inds = []

# foreach row of `df1`...
for row1 in df1.values:
    # these will keep track of min so-far
    min_dist = np.inf
    min_ind = None
    # foreach row of `df2`...
    for j, row2 in enumerate(df2.values):
        # squared distance
        dist = ((row1 - row2) ** 2).sum()
        # is less than minimum so far?
        if dist < min_dist:
            # then update min distance and index
            min_dist = dist
            min_ind = j
    # one row of `df1` finished; save its corresponding row's index
    min_inds.append(min_ind)

# Now we form `df3` with `iloc` as before
df3 = df2.iloc[min_inds]
```

which gives the same result but could be more memory-efficient.

Comment: Mustafa Aydin, just a side note.  This works great, however for large dataframes a siginifcant amount of memory is required resulting in Memory Error: Unable to allocate 
array with shape (x, x) and datatype.  Although slow, seems like a for loop is maybe more suitable for these cases.

Comment: @SasCom thanks for the time-memory tradeoff remark.

Comment: Aydin, sorry I'm new to all this! I guess I'm trying to politely ask how I could implement such a for loop for this reason.

Comment: hey @SasCom, I tried to write a for loop implementation with comments. It gives the same result but could be more memory friendly as you remarked. Hope this helps.

Comment: Aydin, Your help here is hugely appreciated!